# Converting a COLLADA "polygons" structure to a "polylist" structure

Tags: python, collada

I am attempting to import COLLADA files into my application to display 3D models. I am using PyCollada as it makes parsing the file pretty simple, but unfortunately they do not support polygons with holes. A polygon (at least when exported from Google Sketchup) is considered as having holes if there is another smaller polygon inside of it.

My program doesn't need to know about the holes, it just needs to know the boundary vertices of each polygon and then will handle holes itself. As such, I am trying to convert the COLLADA "polygons" structures (those used for polygons with holes) to "polylist" structures (polygons without holes).

Here's an example of what part of the file looks like before I touch it:

```
<polylist count="4" material="Material2">
        <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#ID8" />
        <vcount>3 3 3 3</vcount>
        <p>16 17 18 22 23 24 28 29 30 34 35 36</p>
</polylist>
<polygons count="1" material="Material2">
        <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#ID8" />
        <ph>
                <p>0 1 2 3</p>
                <h>4 5 6 7</h>
                <h>8 9 10 11</h>
        </ph>
</polygons>
```

Here we have a "polylist" that contains 4 polygons, and a "polygons" that contains 1 polygon with 2 subsurfaces or "holes" in it (signified by the `<h>` tags). If say we had `<polygons count="3"`, that would mean there would be 2 more sets of `<ph>` tags, each with 1 `<p>` tag and 1 or more `<h>` tags.

There is a `<float_array>` tag above this that contains a list of vertices for the points in each surface; the numbers in the `<p>` tags are the indices for each group of 3 coordinates. The `<vcount>` tag represents the number of vertices each polygon has.

I wrote a piece of code that changes the file for each pair of "polylist" and "polygons" with a matching material and source ID. It will change the previous code block to the following:

```
<polylist count="5" material="Material2">
        <input offset="0" semantic="VERTEX" source="#ID8" />
        <vcount>3 3 3 3 4</vcount>
        <p>16 17 18 22 23 24 28 29 30 34 35 36 0 1 2 3</p>
</polylist>
```

Note how I basically appended the `<p>` tag from the "polygons" structure to the "polylist", and updated `<vcount>` to reflect the number of points in the new surface that was added.

This is all the changes I have made to the file, and it works with a lot of complex models, but it also doesn't work for some. I am unable to find a pattern, but occasionally the surfaces with holes will not show up, and sometimes a few surfaces they are directly connected to do not show up either.

For this reason I think the issue is just some tag attribute that I may not be updating somewhere, but I am not familiar enough with the COLLADA file format to know what the problem is. Everything I did so far just came from analyzing the file and figuring out what things meant, and I haven't been able to find anything else that I think I would need to change.

So, is there anything I should be aware of when editing COLLADA files, such as a reference to the number of polylists/polygons, or ID matching, or anything like that? If I can't figure this out I may just end up parsing in the lost surfaces manually, but it would be much more convenient if I was able to do it through PyCollada.

Comment: A little late, but neither _Assimp_ or Three.js loader handle holes yet.
Specification 1.5 is quite cryptic also about holes. Not even a good example how to handle them.

Comment: @vlzvl I believe my changes actually ended up working correctly. It's been a while since I worked on this but if I remember correctly, the method described above worked but my code was originally skipping some of the polylists. In hindsight it wasn't too hard to manually convert holes into their own surfaces using the COLLADA format. I just needed some time to figure out the bug in my own code.

Comment: i once found a model that it's `<ph> <p> ..` described a flat wall, and `<ph> <h> ..` described _solid_ parts of the model (parsed with `<polylist>` etc.). The resolution was to somehow _subtract_ these solid parts from the flat wall to get the holes filled and therefore get the missing part (easier said than done). Does your solution handles this stuff? Because the fragment posted above just pastes the `<p>`, efficiently covering a bunch of already parsed primitives. Check this [model](http://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/689819) for example.